# Unable to start WAS 8.5.5 from RSA 8.5, times out

Tags: rational-rsa

I am trying to start WAS v8.5.5.4 from RSA v8.5, it seems that the server is started successfully, because I can see in the console "**server server1 open for e-business**" also I can see the java.exe process in the task manager, and I am able to run the administrative console from the browser.
BUT, from RSA it keeps on the starting status with (23%) till it times out and then it changes from Starting, to Stopping, to Stopped.
I tried re-installing the RSA, re-installing WAS, creating new profiles, ...everything but no help.

Can anyone help me on this please? This is really a nightmare now

Comment: I am using 8.5.5.10 version WAS that comes along with RSA . I am getting same situation and it gets timed out after that point of " WSVR0001I: Server server1 open for e-business" . Did you get any solution after that ?